# Is using ground wire between panels required if both panels are already grounded

Tags: electrical

I installed a sub panel in a new garage and it's grounded with an uffer bond and a grounding rod to the panel but my electri

Comment: You can [edit] your question to finish it.

Comment: Is this garage attached to the house, or a separate (detached) building?

Answer (score 1):

Since you said sub panel yes a ground wire or metallic conduit is required from the source. This has been code since since the 90’s.